# Definition of metric and inner product in diff geo and definition of isometry.

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, euclidean-geometry, inner-products, isometry

**Question 1:**
Does the metric define the inner product or does the inner product define the metric?
I have 
$$(u,v) := \delta_{ij} u^i v^j$$
and I don't know if the $\delta$ is the metric or just the delta function. In the definition of the metric tensor one also uses the inner product but in that case it is always $$(u,v) := u^i v^i$$
So I guess the metric defines the inner product. Is that correct?

**Question 2:**
In the definition of an isometry, $\phi$ we have
$$(u,v)_{g_1} = (\phi(u), \phi(v))_{g_2}$$
What does this notation mean? Simpily
$$
g_{1_{ij}} u^i v^i = g_{2_{ij}} \phi(u)^i \phi(u)^j
$$
or something else?

Comment: An inner product is an "example" of a metric. Not all metrics are inner products, since for example positive definiteness may fail (for example, the Minkowski metric). I prefer to think of a metric as being a parametrized "inner product", where the parametrization space is, say, your manifold $M$. The "inner product" is on the fiber of some vector bundle $E \to M$.

Comment: Ponder [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Mathematical_Spaces.svg/1024px-Mathematical_Spaces.svg.png) as well: Every inner product induces a norm induces a metric induces a topology.

Comment: Also, try to prove that if $\phi$ is an isometry then it is injective.

Answer (score 1):

If $c:(I,|\ |)\rightarrow (X,d)$ is a continous curve in metric space, then define a length of $c$ to be $$ \lim_n\ \sum_{i=1}^n\ d(c(t_i),c(t_{i+1})) $$ where $t_i$ is a partition on $I$.

Here if $p=c(0),\ q=c(1)$, then infimum of lengths of curves between $p$ and $q$ is intrinsic metric. One of example of intrinsic metric is norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here if norm satisfies $\| v-w\|^2 + \|v+w\|^2 =2(\|v\|^2+\|w\|^2)$, then the norm is in fact inner product $g$. Further, in inner product space we can define a length of curve as followes : $$ {\rm length}\ c =\int_0^1\ g(c'(t),c'(t))^\frac{1}{2}\ dt \ \ast$$

Consider inner product space $(X,g)$. From $\ast$, we have a metric $d_g$ which is a infimum of length of curves. If $f :(X,g)\rightarrow (X',g')$ is bijective isometry, then $f$ is isometry between $d_g,\ d_{g'}$, i.e. $$ d_g(x,y)=d_{g'}(f(x),f(y))$$